# Trimming a NSString without extending it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring, trim

I want to trim a string to 50 characters (if it's too long), so I decided to use the following method.

```
someString = [someString stringByPaddingToLength: 50 withString: @"" startingAtIndex: 0];
```

Can I pass an empty string after the `withString` argument? I don't want to crash my app when the method tries to add the string until `someString` is 50 characters in length. I'm afraid it's gonna be bad because it will have to iterate the string `[someString length] / 0` times.

Should I use `nil` instead or search for another way to do the trimming?

Thank you.

Comment: @Jason Boyle: As a Objective-C and Cocoa beginner, I'm not experienced enough to know where the error (one of the 50 I currently have) lies. It can be anywhere. Even if I started a new project just for this, I would probably make even more mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you're using the `stringByPaddingToLength:...` method, if you want to trim a string. I'd have thought that the `substringToIndex:` [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method would be a more logical solution.

For example:

```
NSString *testString = @"This is a test string that contains over fifty characters. Exciting, yet true.";

if([testString length] > 50) {
    // The source string is long enough to grab a substring of.
    NSString *truncatedString = [testString substringToIndex:50];
}
else {
    // The source string is already less than fifty characters.
    NSString *truncatedString = [NSString stringWithString:testString];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is more simple. :-)

Answer (score 2):

why not use `-[NSString substringToIndex:]`?